# Chart.js x-axis label mirroring on a vertical bar chart

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

Chart.js does not support the "mirror" option on vertical "bar" chart.
I tried to search for a workaround but i did not find any help on internet.

I wrote a workaround solution but there's only one thing to solve to be a perfect mirroring:

- align text at the bottom axis.

[Actual text alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSkZk.png)

Somebody can help me to fix this?

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: ["ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE", "SIX", "SEVEN", "EIGHT"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Quota mensile",
      backgroundColor: [
        "rgba(255, 255, 153, 1)",
        "rgba(255, 255, 153, 1)",
        "rgba(255, 255, 153, 1)",
        "rgba(255, 255, 153, 1)",
        "rgba(255, 255, 153, 1)",
        "rgba(255, 255, 153, 1)",
        "rgba(255, 255, 153, 1)",
        "rgba(255, 255, 153, 1)"
      ],
      borderColor: [
        "rgba(255, 255, 153, 1)",
        "rgba(255, 255, 153, 1)",
        "rgba(255, 255, 153, 1)",
        "rgba(255, 255, 153, 1)",
        "rgba(255, 255, 153, 1)",
        "rgba(255, 255, 153, 1)",
        "rgba(255, 255, 153, 1)",
        "rgba(255, 255, 153, 1)"
      ],
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [10, 11, 18, 10, 13, 28, 12, 16]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          maxRotation: 90,
          minRotation: 90,
          display: "top"
        },
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        display: false
      }]
    },
    tooltips: {
      enabled: true
    },
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    responsive: true
  }
});

Chart.plugins.register({
  /* Adjust axis labelling font size according to chart size */
  id: "responsiveXlabels",
  beforeDraw: function(c) {
    var chartHeight = c.chart.height;
    var size = (chartHeight * 2.5) / 100;
    var xAxis = c.scales["x-axis-0"];
    xAxis.options.ticks.minor.fontSize = size;
    xAxis.height = 10;
    xAxis.minSize.height = 10;
    c.options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.padding = -size * 4.5;
    xAxis.margins.bottom = size * 12.5;
  },
  afterDraw: function(c) {
    c.options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.padding = -158;
  }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="myChart" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
```

the responsiveXlabel plugin is used to transform text on resize.

Hope this helps who wants to implement mirroring on X Axis and satisfy responsive request.

Fiddle link to my solution: [Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/un8f7kmc/5/)

I used a chart.js 2.8.0 modified version that you can find at [this link](https://codepen.io/kurkle/pen/ZVQBLQ?editors=1111)
A CodePEN BY Jukka Kurkela